# Shortlist of problems in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, problem-solving

A while ago I remember seeing a very nice shortlist of problems in linear algebra. It was a list of about 40-50 problems. The idea was that if you solve them, you learn linear algebra very well and you don't need to spend any more time on it. I mean, it was a super concise but somewhat complete intro to the subject via solving problems.

It was starting with what it a basis of a vector space, going through basic constructions (sums, quotients), eigenvalues and eigenvectors, Jordan normal form, bilinear forms and their classification, different linear transformations associated to forms (like self-adjoint transformations et.c. ) and ending with discussion of multilinear algebra.

Unfortunately, I can't find it now, and I don't remember at all where I saw it (it was a very long time ago).

> Have you seen any shortlist like that? Could you, please, give me a reference?

Thank you very much!

I hope the question is not too vague.

Comment: Hmmm... I doubt greatly that **any** list of 40-50 problems in linear algebra can be a faithful, true text to whether you're ready to stop "spending more time with linear algebra"...perhaps that's true for *basic* linear algebra, say finite dimensional, and even that I wouldn't be very sure.

Comment: you can see this link.....http://hans.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/504/la.pdf

Comment: @Timbuc I agree with you and disagree at the same time. I am not looking for a problem list for complete beginners, and it doesn't mean that the problems tell you *everything*. It's just if you know how to solve them, it means you know enough of linear algebra.

Comment: @RipanSaha Thanks for the link! I have seen that. It's nice, but it's not what I am looking for. First of all, it's pretty long. Second, it's rather computational. I am looking for a short list of problems, and not for complete beginners, but for someone who already knows some basics like row reduction, but is not familiar or is not familiar enough with more abstract "coordinate-free" approach to linear algebra.