# best book for practicing unsolved problems in differential equation and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I started reading differential equation and linear algebra. Can anyone provide the link/book name where I may get many questions to practice. Generally, in the end of book only few problems are there. I want to solve as many questions as possible.

Comment: Aren't these "books" called *textbooks*?

Comment: @Nameless ... yeah... I have text books like schaum's series and Lin alg by Otto.

Comment: See this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036925/shortlist-of-problems-in-linear-algebra